# Can't get MouseListener to work on Hexagon (a generated polygon)

Tags: java, swing

I'm generating a hexagon grid and am able to do so but when I add a MouseListener to the individual hexagons (when they're created) it's almost as if they're behind something because hovering/clicking on a hexagon will not register or do anything for that matter. I want to be able to eventually interact with the hexagons but can't do that if I can't get this to work.

My main GUI elements:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game2
{
    public Game2(int radius,int num_hexes)
    {
    if(num_hexes%2==0) throw new AssertionError("Can't generate map with 
    an even number of hexagons.");

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,1));

    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setTitle("HexGame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Rectangle r=frame.getBounds();
    int screen_height=r.height;
    int screen_width=r.width;

    Hexes2 hexes2=new Hexes2(num_hexes,radius,screen_width,screen_height);

    panel.add(hexes2);
    JScrollPane scroll_pane=new JScrollPane(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll_pane);
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Runnable r=new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new Game2(100,11);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
}
```

My multiple hexagons:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Hexes2 extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
private static List<Polygon> hexagons;
private static int[] rows;
private int radius;

public Hexes2(int num_columns,int radius,int screen_width,int screen_height)
{
    super();

    this.radius=radius;
    hexagons=new LinkedList<Polygon>();
    rows=Functions.columns(num_columns);

    int x=screen_width/6;
    int y=screen_height/2;

    double height=radius*Math.sqrt(3);
    double range=num_columns-rows[0];

    //build by columns, first
    for(int j=0;j<num_columns;j++)
    {
        x+=((3/2)*radius)*1.5015;

        if(j<=Math.floor(num_columns/2)) y=(int) (100-(j*(height/2)));
        else y=(int) ((100-(height*(range/2))+(num_columns-rows[j])*(height/2)));

        for(int i=0;i<rows[j];i++)
        {
            y+=height;
            Hex2 hex=new Hex2(i,radius,x,y);
            hexagons.add(hex.getHex());
        }
    }
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
    setOpaque(false);

    for(int i=0;i<hexagons.size();i++)
    {
        Stroke stroke=new BasicStroke(radius/20, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
        g2.setStroke(stroke);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawPolygon(hexagons.get(i));
    }
}
};
```

My singular hexagon class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Hex2 extends JLabel implements MouseListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int ID;
private Polygon hexagon;

public Hex2(int ID,int r,int x,int y)
{
    super();
    this.ID=ID;

    hexagon=generateHex(r,x,y);

    addMouseListener(this);
}

public Polygon generateHex(int r, int x, int y)
{
    Polygon hexagon=new Polygon();

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {

       /*int _x=(int) (x + r*Math.cos(Math.PI / 3.0 * i));
       int _y=(int) (y + r*Math.sin(Math.PI / 3.0 * i));*/

        int _x=(int) (x + r*Math.cos(i*2*Math.PI/6));
        int _y=(int) (y + r*Math.sin(i*2*Math.PI/6));

       hexagon.addPoint(_x,_y);
    }

    return hexagon;
}

public int getID()
{
    return ID;
}

public Polygon getHex()
{
    return hexagon;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Clicked on hexagon "+ID);

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
};
```

Functions:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Functions
{
//takes in the max width, n (# hexagons), of the largest row (in the middle)
public static int[] columns(int n)
{
    int[] columns=new int[n];
    int deviation=(int) java.lang.Math.floor(n/2);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        columns[i]=n-(java.lang.Math.abs(i-deviation));
    }

    return columns;
}

public static Dimension getScreenSize()
{
    return java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
}
}
```

I apologize for the long code, just wanted to be thorough. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Question edited. Please understand that "I've searched everywhere..." statements do not help us to understand what you've found in your searches or how the info doesn't help you. We need specifics.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for us. What is `Functions` and what does `Functions.columns(num_columns);` do? Better to create and post a valid [mcve] to make debugging easier for both you and us.

Comment: Thanks. Just edited to show what my Functions class has.

Comment: Please see latest edit to answer

Comment: `new BoxLayout(panel,1)` No one who reads your code will know what the `1` is.  Use the meaningful constant [BoxLayout.Y_AXIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html#Y_AXIS) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your MouseListener to your Hex2 JLabels:

```
public Hex2(int ID, int r, int x, int y) {
    super();
    this.ID = ID;
    hexagon = generateHex(r, x, y);
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

These are JLabels that you never add to the GUI, since you create them here in line A:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
        x += ((3 / 2) * radius) * 1.5015;
        if (j <= Math.floor(num_columns / 2))
            y = (int) (100 - (j * (height / 2)));
        else
            y = (int) ((100 - (height * (range / 2)) + (num_columns - rows[j]) * (height / 2)));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows[j]; i++) {
            y += height;
            Hex2 hex = new Hex2(i, radius, x, y);  // ****** [A] *****
            hexagons.add(hex.getHex());  // ****** [B] *****
        }
    }
```

But hex never is added to the GUI. Instead something else, returned by `getHex()` is added, so the MouseListener won't work. A MouseListener needs to be added to a component that is visualized within the GUI for its actions to do anything.

I think that you're using too many components here. Only one component, a JPanel, should do all the drawings and should have the MouseLIstener added to it. Everything else should be **logical** classes that don't extend Swing component classes.

For example, run the code below. It shows that the hex as a non-component class, one that responds to a MouseListener since the listener is added only to the single drawing JLabel. Polygons are shapes and have a `contains(Point p)` method that can be used inside of the mouse listener to allow them to "know" when they've been pressed:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class HexPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Hex2b> hex2bs = new ArrayList<>();
    private int radius;
    private int[] rows;

    public HexPanel(int num_columns, int radius, int screen_width, int screen_height) {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.radius = radius;
        hex2bs = new LinkedList<Hex2b>();
        rows = Functions.columns(num_columns);
        int x = screen_width / 6;
        int y = screen_height / 2;
        double height = radius * Math.sqrt(3);
        double range = num_columns - rows[0];
        // build by columns, first
        for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
            x += ((3 / 2) * radius) * 1.5015;
            if (j <= Math.floor(num_columns / 2))
                y = (int) (100 - (j * (height / 2)));
            else
                y = (int) ((100 - (height * (range / 2)) + (num_columns - rows[j]) * (height / 2)));
            for (int i = 0; i < rows[j]; i++) {
                y += height;
                Hex2b hex = new Hex2b(i, radius, x, y);
                hex2bs.add(hex);
            }
        }
        addMouseListener(new MyMouse());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); // smooth graphics
        // setOpaque(false); // doesn't belong in here
        for (int i = 0; i < hex2bs.size(); i++) {
            Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(radius / 20, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
            Hex2b hex2b = hex2bs.get(i);
            Color color = hex2b.getColor();
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fill(hex2b.getHex());
            g2.setStroke(stroke);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.draw(hex2b.getHex());
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for (Hex2b hex2b : hex2bs) {
                if (hex2b.getHex().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    hex2b.changeColor();
                    repaint();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game2b");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Toolkit toolKit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screen = toolKit.getScreenSize();
        int width = screen.width;
        int height = screen.height;
        frame.getContentPane().add(new HexPanel(11, 100, width, height));
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class Hex2b {
    private static final Color INIT_COLOR = Color.white;
    private static final Color SELECTED_COLOR = Color.red;
    private int ID;
    private Polygon hexagon;
    private Color color = INIT_COLOR;

    public Hex2b(int ID, int r, int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.ID = ID;
        hexagon = generateHex(r, x, y);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void changeColor() {
        color = color == INIT_COLOR ? SELECTED_COLOR : INIT_COLOR;
    }

    public Polygon generateHex(int r, int x, int y) {
        Polygon hexagon = new Polygon();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int _x = (int) (x + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
            int _y = (int) (y + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
            hexagon.addPoint(_x, _y);
        }
        return hexagon;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public Polygon getHex() {
        return hexagon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah that makes more sense.